# Transformation with box-cox in R

Tags: r

I have a vector like x = [7,41;7,32;7,14;6,46;7,36;7,23;7,16;7,28]. I did a shapiro test (shapiro.test) and the result for the p-value = 0.003391826 which means its not normal distributed and so i want to transform it with box cox (or if you have a better idea except of log and square root) into normal form.

This is the command i tried: boxcox_x=boxcox(x~1, lambda = seq(2,3,1/10), plotit = TRUE, eps=1/50, xlab=expression(lambda), ylab="log-Likelihood"). After this i saw in the diagram for example lambda = -2. 
Then i wrote lambda.max=boxcox_x$x[which.max(boxcox_ph$y)] and the lambda value from this code was completely different from what i could see in the diagram

then i wrote: x_new=bcPower(x, lambda.max, jacobian.adjusted = FALSE) because i thought this code will give me my new vector which should be normal distributed but the result was completely different

Can anybody help me in an easy way of explaining (I am an newcomer)

Thank you

Comment: It would help us to know what does it mean "it didn't work", did you recieve an error, (which error)?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include this information, also include the diagram (and if you could make the cod minimal reproducible it would be even better)

Comment: Which boxcox are you talking of about this [one](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/boxcox.html)?

Comment: Yes, i think so

Answer (score 0):

Getting a good approximation of the distribution is a bit of an art that depends on the context.

A bigger problem you may have is that you have a small sample size which could lead to unreliable estimates of the p-value or representation of the data in any distribution.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this question: I want to make a Bartlett test of a matrix, is this possible? (45 x 8 Matrix)

Comment: For shapiro test for a matrix i found this: do.call(rbind, lapply(Dateiname, function(x) shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")])) an it works!

Comment: If you still need to do more, I would also look into ddply and family of functions in the plyr package. ( [Tutorial to get you started](http://seananderson.ca/2013/12/01/plyr.html) )